# Elements in tabular environment won't right align

Tags: tables, texmaker

I'm trying to format my resume and everything is working fine except in one table the dates won't right align. The weird thing is that I use the exact same code for another tabular environment and it works out fine. Need help figuring how to fix this. Here's the tex file I used https://www.dropbox.com/s/kref3cnudug88qu/AnonReddit.tex?dl=0

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Note that posting code elsewhere doesn't obviate the need for an MWE. Your question should be of use to future users, even if you do not keep the problematic code in your dropbox permanently!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with TeXMaker?

Answer (score 1):

You are defineing the columns as `\begin{tabular}{p{13cm} r}`. Define instead these with the help of `array` package

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.65\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
```

Then use them like

```
\begin{tabular}{LR}
```

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}   %% remove demo
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color,showframe}   %% showframe just for demo, remove
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.65\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.45\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth}@{} }
  \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
  & Engineering Co-op Program & Phone 604 822 3022 \\
  & Faculty of Applied Science & Fax 604 822 3449 \\
  & 2385 East Mall & eng.coop@ubc.ca\\
  & Vancouver, BC Canada V6T 1Z4 & www.ubcengineeringcoop.com \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\textbf{First Last}\\
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}

\subsection*{\color{cyan}EDUCATION}

\begin{tabular}{LR}
\large\textbf{University of British Columbia} & \textbf{September, 2013 - January, 2015} \\
\textbf{\textit{Bachelor of Applied Science - Mechanical Engineering }}  (GPA: 3.4 / 4.33)  \\
\end{tabular}
\subsection*{\color{cyan}TECHNICAL SKILLS}
    \begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm} p{5.5cm} p{5.5cm}}
    \textbf{Computer} & \textbf{Electrical} & \textbf{Mechanical} \\
    $\bullet$ MATLAB & $\bullet$ Oscilloscope & $\bullet$ Basic Machining Safety \\
    $\bullet$ SolidWorks & $\bullet$ Signal Generator & $\bullet$ Mechanical Design \\
    $\bullet$ C & $\bullet$ Soldering Iron\\
    $\bullet$ LaTex & $\bullet$ Breadboard\\
    $\bullet$ Excel
    \end{tabular}

\subsection*{\color{cyan}TECHNICAL PROJECTS}

\begin{tabular}{LR}
\large \textbf{UBC Baja} & \textbf{October, 2014 - Present}\\
$\bullet$ Recreated a complex gearbox to establish accurate sizing and mounting points relative to each other to ensure proper fit in vehicle\\
$\bullet$ Independently constructed a basic chassis model in SolidWorks, using many\\ instances of reference geometry and weldments \\
\\

\large\textbf{Graphing Script} & \textbf{October, 2014} \\
$\bullet$ Developed a MATLAB script that analyzes track data from the UBC Electrical Car Club E-Beetle and produces useful graphs  \\
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{\color{cyan}WORK EXPERIENCE}

\begin{tabular}{LR}
\large \textbf{Hatch} & \textbf{March, 2013 } \\
\textbf{\textit{Student Job Shadow}} \\
$\bullet$ Used Microsoft Excel to calculate percent slurry produced from a basic flow diagram
$\bullet$ Delivered a humorous presentation on Microsoft PowerPoint about my student work week experience  \\
\\
\large \textbf{BC Soccer} & \textbf{September, 2011 - March, 2013} \\
\textbf{\textit{Junior Referee}} \\
$\bullet$ Established a pressure free environment in which kids could learn from mistakes while also managing enthusiastic coaches and parents \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other minor errors like:

`\large` is a switch, use like `\large text` not `\large{Text}`. It is better to add `@{}` to eliminate the space at few places like I did in the very first table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `tabularx`. I also used `enumitem` to insert itemìze environments, with simplifies your code (less rows) and gives more control on the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow, array, tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, noitemsep, topsep=4pt}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{ p{0.45\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.25\textwidth} }
    \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{s2b282.png}}
      & Engineering Co-op Program & Phone 604 822 3022 \\
      & Faculty of Applied Science & Fax 604 822 3449 \\
      & 2385 East Mall & eng.coop@ubc.ca \\
      & Vancouver, BC Canada V6T 1Z4 & www.ubcengineeringcoop.com \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{center}
  \LARGE
  \textbf{First Last}\\
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}

  \subsection*{\color{cyan}EDUCATION}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X >{\bfseries}r}
    \large{\textbf{University of British Columbia}} & September, 2013 -- January, 2015 \\
    \textbf{\textit{Bachelor of Applied Science - Mechanical Engineering }} (GPA: 3.4 / 4.33) \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \subsection*{\color{cyan}TECHNICAL SKILLS}
  \begin{tabular}{p{5.5cm} p{5.5cm} p{5.5cm}}
    \textbf{Computer}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item MATLAB
    \item SolidWorks
    \item C
    \item LaTeX
    \item Excel
    \end{itemize}
      & \textbf{Electrical}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Oscilloscope
    \item Signal Generator
    \item Soldering Iron
    \item Breadboard
    \end{itemize}
      & \textbf{Mechanical}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Basic Machining Safety
    \item Mechanical Design
    \end{itemize}
  \end{tabular}

  \subsection*{\color{cyan}TECHNICAL PROJECTS}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X >{\bfseries}r}
    %{\large\textbf{UBC Baja}} \\
    %$\bullet$ Recreated a complex gearbox to establish accurate sizing and mounting points relative to each other to ensure proper fit in vehicle\\
    %$\bullet$ Independently constructed a basic chassis model in SolidWorks, using many\\ instances of reference geometry and weldments
    {\large\textbf{UBC Baja}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Recreated a complex gearbox to establish accurate sizing and mounting points relative to each other to ensure proper fit in vehicle
    \item Independently constructed a basic chassis model in SolidWorks, using many instances of reference geometry and weldments
    \end{itemize}
      & October, 2014 -- Present \\[1.5ex]
    {\large\textbf{Graphing Script}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Developed a MATLAB script that analyzes track data from the UBC Electrical Car Club E-Beetle and produces useful graphs
    \end{itemize}
      & October, 2014
    \\
  \end{tabularx}

  \subsection*{\color{cyan}WORK EXPERIENCE}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X >{\bfseries}r}
    {\large\textbf{Hatch}}\newline
    \textbf{\textit{Student Job Shadow}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Used Microsoft Excel to calculate percent slurry produced from a basic flow diagram
    \item Delivered a humorous presentation on Microsoft PowerPoint about my student work week experience
    \end{itemize}
      & March, 2013
    \\
    {\large\textbf{BC Soccer}} \newline
    \textbf{\textit{Junior Referee}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Established a pressure free environment in which kids could learn from mistakes while also managing enthusiastic coaches and parents
    \end{itemize}
      & September, 2011 -- March, 2013
  \end{tabularx}

  \subsection*{\color{cyan}VOLUNTEER WORK EXPERIENCE}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X >{\bfseries}r}
    {\large\textbf{First United Church}}\newline
    \textbf{\textit{Student Volunteer}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Managed the front desk, monitored phone calls and handed out needed supplies
    \item Worked in a team to move heavy donated furniture to the Church
    \end{itemize}
      & April, 2013
    \\[1.5ex]
    {\large\textbf{Highschool Secondary}} \newline
    \textbf{\textit{Grade Nine Basketball Coach}}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Helped construct the team through decisive evaluations during try-outs
    \item Instructed players how to run a full-court trap independently
    \end{itemize}
      & September, 2011 -- March, 2013
  \end{tabularx}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

[image]